# Construct field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

There is defined field K and polynomial $m \in K[x]$ which is irreducible over K. $K=\mathbb{Q} , m(x) = x^{3} - 2$. I have to choose on of the root $\alpha$ of polynomial $m$ and construct field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Root should be from $\mathbb{C}$. Let's say I chose root $- \sqrt[3]{-2}$. How could I construct that field?

Comment: Use the field axioms.

Comment: Well, how do you normally construct a field extension?

Comment: $- \sqrt[3]{-2} = \sqrt[3]{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your polynomial is irreducible, the field is just $$\mathbb Q(\alpha )=\{a+b\alpha +c\alpha ^2\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb Q\}.$$
Indeed, $$\mathbb Q(\alpha )\cong \mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-2)\cong \{a+b\alpha +c\alpha ^2\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb Q\}.$$